# phpunit path on Ubuntu for Windows

Tags: ubuntu, phpunit

When I try to use Phpunit I get:

```
-bash: /mnt/c/xampp/php/phpunit: C:\xampp\php\.\php.exe^M:

bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I need to use php7.2 that it's installed on my Ubuntu for Windows in /etc/php/7.2

How can I change that path in this case?

Comment: How do you try to use Phpunit? Can you give an example of what you do to start phpunit?

Comment: Just typing `phpunit` in the root of a Laravel project that I've cloned (and it comes with that phunit test working)

Comment: @pmimd: Please try: `vendor/bin/phpunit` instead (while you're in the root)

Comment: @hakre thanks! it works

Comment: @pmimd: I added this as an answer w/ a little bit more context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try: `vendor/bin/phpunit` instead of just `phpunit` (while you're in the root).

This will take the version of phpunit that has been installed with your Composer based project.

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you, that the file on `/mnt/c/xampp/php/phpunit` uses the wrong line breaks.

Open the file in Notepad++ (or any other editor where you can change line breaks), set the line breaks to `UNIX (LF)` and save.

Next: select the correct php binary. Change the path in the first line to match with your php binary. You can get the path from the command: `which php` (or `which php7`).

The line will then look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

Comment: Now I get `-bash: /mnt/c/xampp/php/phpunit: C:\xampp\php\.\php.exe: bad interpreter: No such file or directory` but anyway, that php is not the one that I want to use anymore, that's 5.4, I need to use the installed in my Ubuntu for Windows, (7.2)

Comment: Edited to reflect that

Comment: Thanks. Now I get several errors... all due that php on Xampp: `PHP Warning:  require(C:\xampp\php\pear/PHPUnit/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /mnt/c/xampp/php/phpunit on line 43
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\php\pear/PHPUnit/Autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /mnt/c/xampp/php/phpunit on line 43`

Comment: Can't help you on that. It seems that it is easier to just install phpunit on the linux subsystem. This will take care of all the path problems as well